# If H, H' are subgroups of G and $H \bigcup H'$ is also a subgroup of G, then it holds that $H \subset H' \lor H' \subset H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I've come up with this proof but I'm not sure that the last step is correct, where I state that the last case is impossible.

**Statement:**

If H, H' are subgroups of G and $H \bigcup H'$ is also a subgroup of G, then it holds that $H \subset H' \lor H' \subset H$.

**Proof:**

Assume that $H \not \subset H'$ (proof for the case $H' \not \subset H$ is identical to the one below).

Let's take $a \in H \setminus H'$, implying by the definition of a subgroup that in this case also $a^{-1} \in H \setminus H'$.

Since H, H' are subgroups of G then it also holds that $e \in H \bigcap H' \subset H \bigcup H' \subset G$.

Then for any $b \in H'$ it'd hold that $b = be = b(aa^{-1}) = (ba)a^{-1}$. Since $a^{-1} \in H$, it is only left to show that also $(ba) \in H$.

Since $b,a \in H \bigcup H'$, then $ba \in H \bigcup H'$. So there are these cases to check:

$$
1) \ ba \in H \land ba \not \in H'\\
2) \ ba \in H \land ba \in H' \\
3) \ ba \not \in H \land ba \in H' \\
$$

The first two cases correspond to $ba \in H$. Hence it is only required to check the last case.
That case is, however, not possible, since $a \not \in H'$. Therefore, it holds that since $b = (ba)a^{-1}$, then $b \in H$, so it follows that $H' \subset H$.

$ \blacksquare $

Comment: Looks correct, though it's a relatively complicated proof.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. :D My proofs are usually like this. Do you have a shorter version using another approach? Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Sui already did that. Everything is based on the fact that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then a product of an element in $H$ with an element outside of $H$ must be an element outside of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. You have $b\in H'$ and $ba\in H'$, therefore $a=b^{-1}ba\in H'$ which is a contradiction.

But your proof can be modified shorter.

Suppose $a\in H\backslash H'$. Take arbitary $b\in H'$. Since $a\notin H'$ and $a=abb^{-1}$, $ab$ can't be in $H'$. Therefore $ab\in H$ and $b=a^{-1}ab\in H$.